# How to avoid video overlapping

Tags: video, fancybox, embed

I'm using the FancyBox plugin for my web application, On one of my pages, I have a video section which we are displaying different formats like (youtube, avi, mpeg, mov etc).

On the same page when i click on FancyBox popup link, The embedded Video section is still lays over the FancyBox popup. I did a bit of z-index, wmode, transparent and opaque experimenting and still no results.

So the question is how to avoid that? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `wmode` attribute of each video to `opaque`.

Comment: Actually Im using jQuery Media plugin, the wmode:'transparent' param is not getting rendered.

Comment: it should be `opaque` ...you have to pass it in both, within the `<object>` tag as parameter `<param name="wmode" value="opaque">` and within the `<embed>` tag as attribute: `<embed wmode="opaque".... `